# Why is the URL for Signal Processing dsp.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, meta

Here's a silly question:

Why is the URL for Signal Processing `dsp.stackexchange.com`? What does *DSP* stand for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digital Signal Processing, what else?

Comment: Oh. Well that makes sense. I feel a bit silly now.